# How do I setup a sip account with pennytel in empathy or ekiga in ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, voip, empathy

I am trying to get my PennyTel VOIP account working in ubuntu 10.04.  I know ubuntu use to use ekiga for sip calls.  I also know that ubuntu now uses empathy for sip calls.

However I can't get either program to work with my VOIP provider.  In empathy I have no idea what details to enter.  How does it know I want to use pennytel?  What is my user name?  I tired mypennytelusername@sip.pennytel.com but it did not work.

In Ekiga I can't figure out how to use a sip provider.  It looks like I can only use the Ekiga sip provider, which I don't want to use because I already have a PennyTel account.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Glen.

Answer (score 1):

http://community.plus.net/forum/index.php/topic,86593.0.html/